# Retrieving information from a text file. Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Basically I am trying to read information from three text files in which it contains unique information.

The way the text file is setup is this:

```
textA.txt
----------------
something.awesome.com
something2.awesome.com
something3.awesome.com
...

textB.txt
----------------
123
456
789
...

textC.txt
----------------
12.345.678.909
87.65.432.1
102.254.326.12
....
```

Now what its suppose to look like when i output it something like this

```
something.awesome.com : 123 : 12.345.678.909
something2.awesome.com : 456 : 87.65.432.1
something3.awesome.com : 789 : 102.254.326.12
```

The code I am trying now is this:

```
for each in `cat site.txt` ; do
    site=`echo $each | cut -f1`

    for line in `cat port.txt` ; do
        port=`echo $line | cut -f1`

        for this in `cat ip.txt` ; do
            connect=`echo $this | cut -f1`

            echo "$site : $port : $connect"
        done
    done
done
```

The result I am getting is just crazy wrong and just not what i want. I don't know how to fix this.

**I want to be able to call the information through variable form.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
paste testA.txt testB.txt testC.txt | sed -e 's/\t/ : /g'
```

Output is:

```
something.awesome.com : 123 : 12.345.678.909
something2.awesome.com : 456 : 87.65.432.1
something3.awesome.com : 789 : 102.254.326.12
```

**Edit:** Here is a solution using pure `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                         

exec 7<testA.txt
exec 8<testB.txt
exec 9<testC.txt

while true
do
    read site <&7
    read port <&8
    read connect <&9

    [ -z "$site" ] && break

    echo "$site : $port : $connect"
done

exec 7>&-
exec 8>&-
exec 9>&-
```

Comment: The thing is I want to call it through variable form. As in echo "$site : $port : $connect"

Comment: meaning like if i want to call the first website with the first port number and the first connect ip. the reason i want to do that is because those variables need to be sent to another script one line at a time meaning the first line from each text file goes through the first time then the second line the second time and etc.

Comment: This works perfectly but just for my understanding can you explain to me what all the exec stuff does? I am really new to this.

Comment: It's just opening files and assigning them to file descriptors.  The [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) discusses it the section on [Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections).

Comment: A little simpler would be to just use input redirection directly on the loop: `while true; do ...; done 7<textA.txt 8<textB.txt 9<textC.txt`. Also, the `-u` option for read selects the file descriptor to read from.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [paste](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/) ?

e.g.

```
$ paste testA.txt testB.txt
```

etc. The **-d** operator will specify a separator character.

A related utility is the SQL-like [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join), which you can use in scenarios where you have to join using fields common to your input files.

Comment: The `-d` argument won't let you introduce multi-character delimiters, which is why I opted for the call to `sed`

Answer (score -1):

```
head -2 /etc/hosts | tail -1 | awk '{print$2}'
```

where `/etc/hosts` is the name of a file.
`(head -2 )` is used to retrieve top 2 lines from the file.
`(tail -1)` is used to retrieve only last one line outputed from `(head -2)`.
`(awk '{print$2}')` is used to print the 2nd column of line outputted from `(tail -1)`.